# Computing GPA of list of Student ID

Tags: java, gpa

Beginner in JAVA. I'm trying to print the GPA of the students. Find the below instruction the problem.

We can have only 3 grades: A, B, C correspond to the points 4,3,2. Let's say if a student has
received the grades A,A,A, and B. GPA = (4+4+4+3) / 4 = 3.75.

calculateGPA should return the array of GPA of students.

Input: 
StudentList = {1001, 1002}
studentgrades = {{'A','A','A','B'},{'A','B','B'}};

Output:(Expected)

3.75, 3.333

Output:(Actual)

4.00, 0.00

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class StudentUtil {

        public static double[] calculateGPA(int[] studentIdList, char[][] studentsGrades) {

            double[] Grades = new double[studentIdList.length];

            for(int i = 0; i < studentsGrades.length; i++) {
                double sumGrades = 0.0;

                for(int j = 0; j < studentsGrades.length; j++) {

                    if(studentsGrades[i][j] == 'A') {
                        sumGrades += 4;
                    }
                    else if(studentsGrades[i][j] == 'B') {
                        sumGrades += 3;
                    }
                    else if(studentsGrades[i][j] == 'C') {
                        sumGrades += 2;
                    }
                }
                Grades[i++] = sumGrades / studentsGrades.length;
            }

            return Grades;
        }

   //(Test Case)

    import static java.lang.System.out;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import static java.lang.System.out;

    public class TestStudentUtil {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            int[] studentIdList = { 1001, 1002 };
            char[][] studentsGrades = { { 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B' }, { 'A', 'B', 'B' } };

            double[] results = StudentUtil.calculateGPA(studentIdList, studentsGrades);

            for (double result : results) {
                out.printf("%.2f\n", result);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Your two loops loop from 0 to studentsGrades.length. And for some reason I can't understand, you have i++ twice. And you divide by the wrong number, too. Extract a method to compute the average for a single array. That will make things much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the inner loop: your loop condition is `j < studentsGrades.length`, when it should be `j < studentsGrades[i].length` to iterate over all entries of the array `studentsGrades[i]`.

A cleaner way to write this code is to use an enhanced `for` loop, since you just need the values anyway, not the indices. As well as being easier to read, this avoids the possibility of a subtle mistake like writing the wrong loop bound.

```java
            for(int i = 0; i < studentsGrades.length; i++) {
                double sumGrades = 0.0;
                char[] currentGrades = studentsGrades[i];

                for(char grade : currentGrades) {
                    if(grade == 'A') {
                        sumGrades += 4;
                    }
                    else if(grade == 'B') {
                        sumGrades += 3;
                    }
                    else if(grade == 'C') {
                        sumGrades += 2;
                    }
                }
                Grades[i] = sumGrades / currentGrades.length;
            }
```

The division at the end had the same problem; you need to divide by how many grades this student has, not by the number of students.

Note also that `i++` is already done in your outer loop's update step, so you shouldn't also do it in the line `Grades[i] = ...`.

Comment: Hi @kaya3 Please explain me this logic "char[] currentGrades = studentsGrades[i];".  I'm not getting clear idea about it.

Comment: `studentGrades` is an array of arrays - one array per student - so `studentGrades[i]` is just the array of student `i`'s grades.